# Flutter Image Picker Crash

Tags: android, flutter

I want to ask if you ever encounter the app being crash right after selecting an image from the gallery/camera using [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker#-readme-tab-) plugin version 0.6.3+4 on Android? Already searching for an answer for 1 week and no answer can help me, because I think it's my project that has some compatibility problems.

Here is my case. On my original project, the app always crashes right after selecting an image from the gallery/camera, but if I use the plugin to a new clean project with just only one button with onPress function to select the image, it works, no crash happens.

So maybe I think there's something inside my original project that makes this crash happens. Here is the code about how I use the image_picker

```
  imageSelectorGallery() async {
    fileProfilePicture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );

    if(fileProfilePicture != null) {
      setState(() {
        uploadPicture();
      });
    }
  }
```

And the function is called by this widget

```
new GestureDetector(
  onTap: () { 
    imageSelectorGallery();
  },
  child: new Container(
    child: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue,
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
          child: new Icon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.image,
            size: 22.0,
            color: Colors.white
          ),
        ),
        new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 3.0)),
        new Text(
          "Gallery",
          style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 12.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

of course, there's a camera button that called another similar function for taking an image from the camera, but I think it'll be too long for a question if I'm adding it, besides both of them are causing the same crash.

and here is the list of my plugins that I used inside the project, I don't know if there's some plugin that can't be used together or not, but I hope this can make my question clearer.

```
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  flutter_calendar_carousel: 1.3.16
  bubble_tab_indicator: "^0.1.4"
  chewie: ^0.9.7
  video_player: ^0.10.1+3
  toast: ^0.1.3
  shimmer: ^1.0.0
  flutter_responsive_screen: ^1.0.0
  flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.7
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.19+8
  audioplayer: 0.5.2
  image_picker: ^0.6.3+4
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
  sticky_headers: "^0.1.8"
  flutter_speed_dial: ^1.2.1
  url_launcher: ^5.1.2
  image_picker_saver: ^0.3.0
  smooth_star_rating: ^1.0.3
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.1+1
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.2.8
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"
  youtube_player: ^3.5.0
  youtube_player_flutter: ^6.0.3+2
  wakelock: ^0.1.3+4
```

and here is the log right before the gallery opened until after the app crash.

```
D/ViewRootImpl@e8d5055[MainActivity](19819): ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e8d5055[MainActivity](19819): ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@e8d5055[MainActivity](19819): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager(19819): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@7634a6a[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(19819): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/SurfaceView(19819): onWindowVisibilityChanged(8) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{9f9cd1 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1920} of ViewRootImpl@e8d5055[MainActivity]
D/SurfaceView(19819): show() Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.example.test_new_image_picker/com.example.test_new_image_picker.MainActivity@9f9cd1@1[19819])/@0x7cc5bde io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{9f9cd1 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1920}
D/SurfaceView(19819): surfaceDestroyed callback.size 1 #2 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{9f9cd1 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1920}
W/libEGL  (19819): EGLNativeWindowType 0xd622b808 disconnect failed
D/SurfaceView(19819): destroy() Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.example.test_new_image_picker/com.example.test_new_image_picker.MainActivity@9f9cd1@1[19819])/@0x7cc5bde io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{9f9cd1 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1920}
W/libEGL  (19819): EGLNativeWindowType 0xd622b008 disconnect failed
D/OpenGLRenderer(19819): eglDestroySurface = 0xf0c74920, 0xd622b000
D/ViewRootImpl@e8d5055[MainActivity](19819): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x5 surface={false 0} changed=true
D/InputTransport(19819): Input channel destroyed: fd=95
D/ViewRootImpl@e8d5055[MainActivity](19819): stopped(true) old=false
D/SurfaceView(19819): windowStopped(true) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{9f9cd1 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1920} of ViewRootImpl@e8d5055[MainActivity]
D/FlutterView(19819): Detaching from a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@53149bd
D/SurfaceView(19819): onWindowVisibilityChanged(4) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{9f9cd1 V.E...... .......D 0,0-1080,1920} of ViewRootImpl@e8d5055[MainActivity]
D/ViewRootImpl@e8d5055[MainActivity](19819): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={false 0} changed=false
D/AndroidRuntime(19819): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(19819): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(19819): Process: com.example.test_new_image_picker, PID: 19819
E/AndroidRuntime(19819): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2342, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:8411 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.test_new_image_picker/com.example.test_new_image_picker.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received image from picker that was not requested
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4643)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4685)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1970)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received image from picker that was not requested
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at io.flutter.plugins.imagepickersaver.ImagePickerDelegate.handleImageResult(ImagePickerDelegate.java:495)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at io.flutter.plugins.imagepickersaver.ImagePickerDelegate.handleChooseImageResult(ImagePickerDelegate.java:434)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at io.flutter.plugins.imagepickersaver.ImagePickerDelegate.onActivityResult(ImagePickerDelegate.java:413)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEnginePluginRegistry$FlutterEngineActivityPluginBinding.onActivityResult(FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.java:634)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.onActivityResult(FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.java:367)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onActivityResult(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:546)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onActivityResult(FlutterActivity.java:594)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7791)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4636)
E/AndroidRuntime(19819):        ... 11 more
I/Process (19819): Sending signal. PID: 19819 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

and I'm using minSdk 21 and targetSdk 28 on the build.gradle, and I use all this permission on my AndroidManifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

So anyone who knows about this problem and how to fix it please tell me, thank you. Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Have you asked the permissions before starting the Camera or Accessing the Gallery? Have you mention all the permissions in Manifest file?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that, already updated it on the question, i already input all the permission including READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE (which i deleted it right now because there's no changes even after i added it, already tried it)

Comment: Have you checked the below answer?

Comment: yup, still not work, same crash still happen, and I think it's not about the permission, there's something else, but I don't know what

Answer (score 4):

found out the problem, with the latest version of Flutter on stable channel 1.12.13+hotfix.9, you can't use plugin image_picker and image_picker_saver together, still don't know why, but you can add a comment to this answer if you know about it, thanks.

Comment: thanks for your answer! It works after I delete `image_picker_saver`.

Answer (score 2):

`Image_picker_saver` will not work with `image_picker` you can use any other plug in similar to `image_picker_saver` like https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver

Answer (score 1):

[https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera) is worst package it cant handle android way camera correctly .... please see flutter camera example and you will land safely with out any issues... [refer this link and copy past last code sinnpet given in that cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using the plugin `permission_handler` is iOS will complain about .plist info. Until you are certain about multiple permission like camera, calendar, contacts etc... I would not prefer to use this.

This is how i did -

```
checkAndRequestCameraPermissions() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    try {
      final image = await picker.getImage(
        source: ImageSource.camera,
        imageQuality: 75,
        maxHeight: 300,
        maxWidth: 400,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.code);
    }
  }
```

you can check for exception code in your catch bloc like `e.code == 'camera_access_denied'` then you can prompt user about enabling it from device Settings, on Android it ask anyway all time if it is not granted/disabled.

Answer (score 1):

by adding  `preferredCameraDevice: CameraDevice.rear` in `pickImage` worked for me.
also add the `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

`image_picker` plugin does not support permissions condition anymore. For instance, when we try to access camera from an app, the app asks us for permission. Now, since `image_picker` plugin has removed that condition, we need to ask the permission manually using `permission_handler` plugin. Read more details about this change [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29422)

Use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) plugin to add the request manually i.e on runtime and you should be able to get rid of this crash.

Sample Code:

```
  // get permissions
  Future<PermissionStatus> _getPermission(perm) async {
    PermissionStatus permission = await PermissionHandler()
        .checkPermissionStatus(perm);
    if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted &&
        permission != PermissionStatus.disabled) {
      Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permisionStatus =
      await PermissionHandler()
          .requestPermissions([perm]);
      return permisionStatus[perm] ??
          PermissionStatus.unknown;
    } else {
      print(permission);
      return permission;
    }
  }

  Future selectGallery() async {
    // check permission
    PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await _getPermission(PermissionGroup.photos);
    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      setState(() {
        accessDenied = false;
        // do your work
      });
    } else {
      accessDenied = true;
      setState(() {});
      throw PlatformException(
        code: 'PERMISSION_DENIED',
        message: 'Access to location data denied',
        details: null,
      );
    }    
  }

  Future selectCamera() async {
    // check permission
    PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await _getPermission(PermissionGroup.camera);
    print(permissionStatus);
    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      setState(() {
        accessDenied = false;
        // do your work
      });
    } else {
      accessDenied = true;
      setState(() {});
      throw PlatformException(
        code: 'PERMISSION_DENIED',
        message: 'Access to location data denied',
        details: null,
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: actually I don't really understand your example, the PermissionHandler() is error if I copy your code, then I tried to read the documentation about the plugin, added "final permisionStatus = await Permission.photos.request();" and "final permisionStatus = await Permission.camera.request();" before selecting the image, then I print the permissionStatus, and the value is PermissionStatus.granted, but my app still crashes

Comment: My example is just to elaborate you how to use permissions before accessing camera or gallery. Many peoples are facing this because of `image_picker` which didn't checked the permission on it's own. If you are getting PermissionStatus.granted, then this should not be the permission issue.

Comment: Can you tell me why are you using `image_picker` and `image_picker_saver` both?

Comment: oh I see, and yeah, already double-checked it, Permission.photos and Permission.camera is Granted, but the app still crashes, it's frustrating and confusing :(

Comment: image_picker_saver is to save/download image, and image_picker is for select/upload image

Comment: Crashes at what time? on image picker opening? or after selecting the image?

Comment: exactly right after I select the image, if from gallery, the gallery is successfully open and all the image is there, I can browse the image freely but after I select the image the app crash, even when I place a print('something') right below fileProfilePicture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);, the "something" doesn't even printed out, if from the camera, the image from the camera can successfully be captured, but the moment I hit the "OK" button to select the image, it crashes, and the print('something') isn't printed out too

Comment: Haven't seen that behavior. Many have this issues but they have resolved this by using `permission_handler` library. Might be you are using so many libraries, so some of them are contradicting with each other, on versions. Try to run `flutter pub upgrade` and `flutter upgrade`

Comment: what's flutter pub upgrade for ? if flutter upgrade i already using flutter with latest version on stable channel

Comment: It's for the package upgrading, the packages you are using

Comment: the same crash still happens :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, you just need to add camera permission in Info.plist file

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>App needs access to photo lib for profile images</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>To capture profile photo please grant camera access</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don´t forget to add permissions in Info.plist for iOS (NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription, NSCameraUsageDescription and NSMicrophoneUsageDescription), and android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" for AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

in case of iOS 14 or later using image picker with InkWell causes the app to crash on the second image selection , [image_picker: 0.6.7+22, flutter:1.22.6], this can be avoided by using GestureDector rather than Inkwell to open the picker

Answer (score 0):

Add this in info.plist

<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>

<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app does not require access to the microphone.</string>

<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>

Answer (score 0):

use get Imagepicker.getImage instead of ImagePicker.pickImage